# Canvas finger drawing opacity is increase after using FloodFill in android

Tags: android, android-canvas, flood-fill

I have canvas drawing app. I successfully done integrating floodfill algorithm for filling color for finger drawing circle and rectangle area. My problem is after filling color on finger drawing circle when i used blur mask brush effect and drawing using finger by blur mask brush then whole blur mask brush drawing is repaint again and again. Here is my code:

```
public class DrawingView extends View {
    private final Paint mDefaultPaint;
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    float x, y;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    LinearLayout drawing_layout;
    private Canvas mLayerCanvas = new Canvas();
    private Bitmap mLayerBitmap;
    final Point p1 = new Point();
    private Stack<DrawOp> mDrawOps = new Stack<>();
    private Stack<DrawOp> mUndoOps = new Stack<>();

    boolean isFill = false;
    private SparseArray<DrawOp> mCurrentOps = new SparseArray<>(0);

    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);

    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        mDefaultPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mDefaultPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mDefaultPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mDefaultPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mDefaultPaint.setStrokeWidth(40);
        mDefaultPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        setSaveEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
        final int pointerCount = MotionEventCompat.getPointerCount(event);

        switch (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event)) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            if (isFill == true) {

                int xx = (int) event.getX();
                int yy = (int) event.getY();
                Point pp = new Point(xx, yy);

                /*Point pp = new Point();
                pp.x = (int) event.getX();
                pp.y = (int) event.getY();*/

                final int sourceColor = mLayerBitmap.getPixel(xx, yy);
                final int targetColor = mDefaultPaint.getColor();

                new TheTask(mLayerBitmap, pp, sourceColor, targetColor)
                        .execute();

//              JniBitmap.floodFill(mLayerBitmap, xx, yy, sourceColor,targetColor);

/*              FloodFill f = new FloodFill();
                f.floodFill(mLayerBitmap, pp, sourceColor, targetColor);*/

            }
            for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
                final int id = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event, p);
                DrawOp current = new DrawOp(mDefaultPaint);
                current.getPath().moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                mCurrentOps.put(id, current);
            }
        }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                if (isFill == false) {

                final int id = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event, 0);
                DrawOp current = mCurrentOps.get(id);
                final int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                for (int h = 0; h < historySize; h++) {
                    x = event.getHistoricalX(h);
                    y = event.getHistoricalY(h);
                    current.getPath().lineTo(x, y);
                }
                x = MotionEventCompat.getX(event, 0);
                y = MotionEventCompat.getY(event, 0);
                current.getPath().lineTo(x, y);
            }
        }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
                final int id = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event, p);
                mDrawOps.push(mCurrentOps.get(id));
                mCurrentOps.remove(id);
            }
            updateLayer();
        }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
                mCurrentOps.remove(MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event, p));
            }
            updateLayer();
        }
            break;

        default:
            return false;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        Bitmap bmp;
        Point pt;
        int replacementColor, targetColor;

        public TheTask(Bitmap bm, Point p, int sc, int tc) {
//          this.bmp = bm;
            mLayerBitmap = bm;
            pd = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            this.pt = p;
            this.replacementColor = tc;
            this.targetColor = sc;
            pd.setMessage("Filling....");
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            FloodFill f = new FloodFill();
//           mLayerBitmap = f.floodFill(bmp, pt, targetColor, replacementColor);
            f.floodFill(mLayerBitmap, pt, targetColor, replacementColor);

//          New Commented Algorithm
//          f.FloodFill(mLayerBitmap, pt, targetColor, replacementColor);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            pd.dismiss();
            invalidate();
            isFill = false;
        }
    }

    public void fillShapeColor(Bitmap mBitmap2) {
        isFill = true;
    }

    public void setDrawing() {
        isFill = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldW, oldH);
        mLayerBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mLayerCanvas.setBitmap(mLayerBitmap);
        updateLayer();
    }

    private void updateLayer() {


        for (DrawOp drawOp : mDrawOps) {
            if (drawOp != null) {
//              drawOp.draw(new Canvas(mLayerBitmap));
                drawOp.draw(mLayerCanvas);
            }
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (isInEditMode()) {
            return;
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(mLayerBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        for (int i = 0; i < mCurrentOps.size(); i++) {
            DrawOp current = mCurrentOps.valueAt(i);
            if (current != null) {
                current.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }

    public void operationClear() {
        mDrawOps.clear();
        mUndoOps.clear();
        mCurrentOps.clear();
        // To Clear Whole Canvas
        mLayerCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        updateLayer();
    }

    public void operationUndo() {
        if (mDrawOps.size() > 0) {
            mUndoOps.push(mDrawOps.pop());
            updateLayer();
        }
    }

    public void operationRedo() {
        if (mUndoOps.size() > 0) {
            mDrawOps.push(mUndoOps.pop());
            updateLayer();
        }
    }

    public void setPaintStrokeWidth(float widthPx) {
        mDefaultPaint.setStrokeWidth(widthPx);
    }

    /*public float getPaintStrokeWidth(){
        return mDefaultPaint.getStrokeWidth();

    }*/

    public void setPaintOpacity(int percent) {
        int alphaValue = (int) Math.round(percent * (255.0 / 100.0));
        mDefaultPaint.setColor(combineAlpha(mDefaultPaint.getColor(),
                alphaValue));
    }

    /*public int getPaintOpacity(){
        this.setPaintOpacity(50);
        return mDefaultPaint.getColor();
    }*/

    public void setPaintColor(String color) {
        mDefaultPaint.setXfermode(null);
        mDefaultPaint.setColor(combineAlpha(Color.parseColor(color),
                mDefaultPaint.getAlpha()));
//      mDefaultPaint.setColor(mDefaultPaint.getAlpha());
    }

    public void setPaintColor(int color) {
        mDefaultPaint.setXfermode(null);
        mDefaultPaint.setColor(combineAlpha(color, mDefaultPaint.getAlpha()));
    }

//  New Created
    public void setEraser(int color){
//      mDefaultPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
        mDefaultPaint.setColor(color);
        mDefaultPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    }

    public void setPaintMaskFilter(MaskFilter filter) {
        mDefaultPaint.setMaskFilter(filter);
    }

    /*public MaskFilter getPaintMaskFilter(){
        return mDefaultPaint.getMaskFilter();

    }*/

    public void setPaintShader(BitmapShader shader) {
        mDefaultPaint.setShader(shader);
    }

    public void setPaintColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {
        mDefaultPaint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
    }

    private static int combineAlpha(int color, int alpha) {
        return (color & 0x00FFFFFF) | ((alpha & 0xFF) << 24);
    }

    private static class DrawOp {
        private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        private final Path mPath = new Path();

        public DrawOp(Paint paint) {
            reset(paint);
        }

        void reset(Paint paint) {
            mPath.reset();
            update(paint);
        }

        void update(Paint paint) {
            mPaint.set(paint);
        }

        void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }

        public Path getPath() {
            return mPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No one can have ans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of research i fond my problem and getting correct it. Below is my code.

```
    if (isFloodFill) {
        if (mZoomMode) {
            return false;
        } else {

            final Point p = new Point();
            float[] mTmpPoint1 = new float[2];

            mTmpPoint1[0] = event.getX() - mPanX;
            mTmpPoint1[1] = event.getY() - mPanY;

            mZoomMatrixInv.mapPoints(mTmpPoint1);

            p.x = (int) (mTmpPoint1[0]);
            p.y = (int) (mTmpPoint1[1]);

            System.out.println("--plotX mTmpPoint0: touch:" + p.x);
            System.out.println("--plotY mTmpPoint0: touch:" + p.y);

            this.mBitmap = getBitmap();
            if (this.mBitmap != null) {

                if(p.x > mBitmap.getWidth() || p.y > mBitmap.getHeight())
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(p.x >= 0 && p.y >= 0)
                    {
                        this.color = this.mBitmap.getPixel(p.x, p.y);   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                // isFilling = false;
                new FloodFillAlgo().execute(p);
                return false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```